# Updating the PTE bits from multiple cores - how do they avoid stepping on each other?

Tags: concurrency, x86, operating-system, paging, page-tables

I've got a question regarding an SMP system with multiple threads belonging to the same process:
Do all these threads share a single page-tree and the accessed and dirty bits of the PTEs in the tree are atomically (read-modify-write-operation) updated (accessed & dirty bit) according to the PTE-caches when they are flushed back?

Or are there up to the number of threads duplicate page-tables which are each dedicated to a single thread while it is running (and recycled if another thread is running) so that there's no need to (rmw-)lock the memory holding the PTE-entries while updating the accessed- and dirty-bits while flushing the PTE-caches?

Answer (score 1):

Every thread of the same process has the same CR3 page table.

Updates to PTE A and D bits are atomic, presumably done by microcode as a sort of atomic-OR.  (IIRC, most modern x86 CPUs handle setting the A or D bit as a microcode assist on the load or store instruction that needs to set a bit that wasn't already set in the TLB entry.)

[How prompt is x86 at setting the page dirty bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924031/how-prompt-is-x86-at-setting-the-page-dirty-bit) quotes Intel's and AMD's manuals on the subject of "Automatic Locking" like the LOCK prefix.

Atomic RMW on updates is relatively cheap compared to the OS having to maintain a copy of each process's page table for each HW thread, aka logical  core (or for each software thread of a process if that was a smaller number).  It's already a slowish microcode assist to have the CPU set a bit.  Also, you don't want N copies of the page tables wasting L3 cache footprint.